# Img next to div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an img next to a div, but at some point it won't let me.

Pictures say more than 1000 words, so here we go...

Please, don't look at the language it is written in. Focus on the code.

**Red circle: How it should be**

**Yellow circle: How it is** 
[image]
[image]

**HTML (stripped down)**

```
<div class="trinnfortrinn">
            <div class="streker venstre">
                <img src="#">
            </div>

            <div class="container rootwizard">

            </div>

            <div class="streker hoyre">
                <img src="#">
            </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (stripped down)**

```
.streker {
    max-width: 200px;
}

.streker img {
    width: 200px;   
}

.venstre {
    float: left;    
}

.hoyre img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.trinnfortrinn .container {
    clear: none;    
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Hope I haven't missed anything. I have really tried to strip it down.

Not sure how many different methodes I have tried, but at least with and without absolute position, with and without margin/padding bottom. Nothing have really helped. I have understood that "float" does not give any value in terms of height, but i have not been able to push it up.

Built in Bootstrap btw.

Could you help me out?

Thanks

[The site can be found here. Please scroll down](http://tinyurl.com/q8yn2rv)

Edit: New images that shows how it should be. The images shows the bottom right arrow/image.

Yellow: How it is

Red: How it should be (approx) DONT bother about the size of the arrow/image, - I just make it bigger so you to see it clearly :)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Might just be me, but it's hard to find a solution without more of your code.

Comment: for `position absolute`, you probably want to specify the `top` or `bottom` property too

Comment: I think the right image needs `bottom:0`, but that would depend on where the bottom of trinnfortrinn actually is. Anyway, why are we not supposed to look at the language?

Comment: @MrLister I don't think he means "not supposed to look at the language". More like "please ignore the language and focus on the problem"

Comment: Sorry if its hard to get it @LynelHudson. I will try to update it in a second. Abdul Ahmad, - I am trying to do so. But if I write buttom:0, its being sent up to the top of the div. If I write top:0, its being sent up to the top of the site. Thanks for clearing that "language" part up. I will add the link to the page in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple way of going about it. Setting a `position` of `absolute` on your `streker` class will allow you position the two images without bothering the rest of the page.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtqcza8s/1/)**

```css
.streker {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 35px;
  background: blue;
}
.venstre {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.hoyre {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="trinnfortrinn">
  <div class="streker venstre">
    <img src="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="container rootwizard">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="streker hoyre">
    <img src="#" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note** I added a bit of content to make sure it wasn't really messing with anything inside the `container` class. Also the two blue boxes represent a placeholder for your image. They will always be in the top left and bottom right of the WINDOW. If your content expands below the screen ( they have to scroll ) the arrows will stay in their same positions and not move with the content.

**Edit** If instead of using `position: absolute;` you use `position: fixed;` the arrows will move with the content instead of being fixed to the window.

Comment: Thanks alot. This seems good, but it didn't work for me. The arrows moves to the very top of the page.... If you want, you can take a look at the site right now by pressing the link above in the question. I won't do any changes if you want to take a look. Btw: I guess you mean the opposite with absolute and fixed? position: fixed means that the  arrows will be fixed to the window, and absolute will move with the content? :)

Comment: @Olen no, I guess I explained it strangely. Fixed will move the bottom arrow with content, so even if you scroll, it will always be on the bottom right of the page. However, with absolute, it will be on the bottom right of the screen, so if you scroll, the content moves past the arrow instead of the arrow moving with it.

Comment: @Olen I changed the `.hoyre` class' `bottom` value to `69px` and it moved the image up to show the entire image. However, I'm still not sure how/when you want these to be displayed.

Comment: thanks, then I just misunderstood you :) Hmm, either I am not understand, or my browser is pretty weird. Right now the arrows are being placed at the very top of the page, - by the slide-image (which isn't a slider). The second image in the question shows how it should be. They should both be in the trinnfortrinn div, one at the top left, and the other one at the bottom right. If I reverse the changes, they will end up like the first image. The one on the bottom right is getting moved down to the other div. --> Thats the problem, it is not by the side of the div...

Comment: @Olen okay I think I get it now. Add `position: relative;` to your `trinnfortrinn` class, and change `position: fixed;` to `absolute` for the `streker` class. Also `.venstre`'s `top` value should be `162px` and `hoyre`'s bottom value should be `29px`. Try that.

Comment: Thanks alot. That solved the question! :) (I changed the top-value to 800px to make it fit tho)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pull-left` this will `float:left` the image and the text

```
<div class="trinnfortrinn container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="streker venstre pull-left col-md-8">
                <img src="#">

            </div>

            <div class=" rootwizard pull-left col-md-4">
                 <!-- some text -->
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

then set

```
.venstre {
    position: relative    
}
```

Note : you are using bootstrap

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. "streker venstre" is correctly placed. Also is "container rootwizard". The reason I have placing them out of the container is because of the 960 grid, - I want the images to be placed at the sides of the screen. The problem is "streker hoyre" which is being placed at the bottom tot he right, but dissapear at the bottom...  Sorry if I am being unclear...